# Merge CiviCRM data from D6 to existing D7 database

Tags: drupal, duplicate-contacts, drupal-6

I need to merge CiviCRM data from a Drupal 6 site into a Drupal 7 site that has an existing CiviCRM installation.
The sites are running under Aegir. In both cases the Drupal and CiviCRM tables are in the same databases. The D6 site is on Civi 5.24.3 with about 45k contacts with lots of organisation memberships + events records. The D7 site is on Civi 5.25.

I understand that I can do the laborious export/import process but am hoping someone has a recipe for a more efficient way.

Comment: so you have data already in the d7 db that need keeping?

Comment: Hi Pete. The d7 site was set up for a once-off conference and has a small amount of contact and event data. I have already exported the d7 civi data back into the d6 site (so don't need to keep the d7 civi data)

Comment: so do you now just need to copy the civi db (skip triggers) from the d6 site to a d7 site?

Comment: ie replace the civi db on the d7 site with the copy from d6?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: If you convert/update the D6 site into a D7 site, can you not then just import / clone the Drupal data/content in the newer site to the former D6/now D7 site?

Comment: Thanks Joe. We had hoped to do that but have a bunch of modules with no easy upgrade path. My developer was also hesitant. I'm going to try exporting / importing the Civi tables per Pete's nudge :-)